# rest-client request time out

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, bitbucket

I am deploying my branch on a new server using BitBucket. However, after I prepared everything, during the deployment, I am getting this error message all the time.

```
DEBUG [076ec2be] Command: cd /opt/webapp/holidale_dev10/releases/20160211212625 && ( export RAILS_ENV="dev10" ; /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm default do bundle exec rake assets:precompile )
DEBUG [076ec2be]    rake aborted!
DEBUG [076ec2be]    RestClient::RequestTimeout: Request Timeout
DEBUG [076ec2be]    /opt/webapp/holidale_dev10/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rest-client-1.8.0/lib/restclient/request.rb:427:in `rescue in transmit'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the timeout of one of my gem's authentication.